# Counting duplicates with XSL and outputting to table

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

Hi im new to XSL and im trying to output a table that shows the customer ID and the number of cars purchased, of customers that have purchased more than 1 car based on my XML file.
An example output would be:

Customer
3
4

Number of Cars
3
2

but what im getting now is:

Customer
3
3
3
4
4
9

Number of Cars
null
null
null
null
null
null

Here is my XML file.

```
<cars>

<car>
    <carID>
            3
    </carID>

    <mobileNumber>

        <areaCode>
                00353
        </areaCode>

        <number>
                8723059
        </number>

    </mobileNumber>

    <customerID>
                3
    </customerID>

    <purchaseDate>

            <dayPurchased>
                        6
            </dayPurchased>

            <monthPurchased>
                        April
            </monthPurchased>

            <yearPurchased>
                        2011
            </yearPurchased>

    </purchaseDate>

</car>

<car>
    <carID>
            4
    </carID>

    <mobileNumber>

        <areaCode>
                00353
        </areaCode>

        <number>
                8723099
        </number>

    </mobileNumber>

    <customerID>
                3
    </customerID>

    <purchaseDate>

            <dayPurchased>
                        6
            </dayPurchased>

            <monthPurchased>
                        April
            </monthPurchased>

            <yearPurchased>
                        2011
            </yearPurchased>

    </purchaseDate>

</car>

<car>
    <carID>
            5
    </carID>

    <mobileNumber>

        <areaCode>
                00353
        </areaCode>

        <number>
                8723777
        </number>

    </mobileNumber>

    <customerID>
                3
    </customerID>

    <purchaseDate>

            <dayPurchased>
                        6
            </dayPurchased>

            <monthPurchased>
                        April
            </monthPurchased>

            <yearPurchased>
                        2011
            </yearPurchased>

    </purchaseDate>

</car>

<car>
    <carID>
            16
    </carID>

    <mobileNumber>

        <areaCode>
                00353
        </areaCode>

        <number>
                8721777
        </number>

    </mobileNumber>

    <customerID>
                4
    </customerID>

    <purchaseDate>

            <dayPurchased>
                        6
            </dayPurchased>

            <monthPurchased>
                        April
            </monthPurchased>

            <yearPurchased>
                        2011
            </yearPurchased>

    </purchaseDate>

</car>

<car>
    <carID>
            166
    </carID>

    <mobileNumber>

        <areaCode>
                00353
        </areaCode>

        <number>
                8722777
        </number>

    </mobileNumber>

    <customerID>
                4
    </customerID>

    <purchaseDate>

            <dayPurchased>
                        6
            </dayPurchased>

            <monthPurchased>
                        April
            </monthPurchased>

            <yearPurchased>
                        2011
            </yearPurchased>

    </purchaseDate>

</car>

<car>
    <carID>
            169
    </carID>

    <mobileNumber>

        <areaCode>
                00353
        </areaCode>

        <number>
                8721787
        </number>

    </mobileNumber>

    <customerID>
                9
    </customerID>

    <purchaseDate>

            <dayPurchased>
                        6
            </dayPurchased>

            <monthPurchased>
                        April
            </monthPurchased>

            <yearPurchased>
                        2011
            </yearPurchased>

    </purchaseDate>

</car>
</cars>
```

Here is my XSL file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">

<html> <head><title>Customers</title></head> <body> <table rules="all">
<thead><tr><th>Customer</th><th>Number of Cars Purchased</th></tr></thead> 
  <xsl:for-each select="cars/car">
  <tr><td>  <xsl:apply-templates select="customerID"/> </td>
  </xsl:for-each>
</table></body></html>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you forgot the closing tr after `<tr><td>  <xsl:apply-templates select="customerID"/> </td>`. What is not working in your transformation? What output do you receive ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways of doing these things, but not sure what you were trying to do there. If you want to do a table based on customers, you can't start by itterating through the cars. You want one customer per line, so you have to itterate through customers counting them.

Something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">

        <html> <head>
            <title>Customers</title></head> <body> 
                <table rules="all">
                    <thead>
                        <tr><th>Customer</th><th>Number of Cars Purchased</th>                            </tr>
                    </thead> 
                    <xsl:for-each select=".//customerID">
                        <xsl:variable name="customerId" select="text()"/>
                        <xsl:if test="not(preceding::customerID) or $customerId != preceding::customerID[1]">
                       <tr>
                           <td>  <xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
                           <td><xsl:value-of select="count(following::customerID[text()=$customerId])+1"/></td>
                       </tr>
                        </xsl:if>
                   </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

although that is a little messy and can be refined a lot (I have to run out!)